# HTML return instead of JSON data

Tags: php, html, json, .htaccess

I am trying to figure out why my PHP code returns the HTML page instead of the JSON data I am looking for. The code essentially allows for uploading of files. If I upload a fairly small file (650KB) all works as expected. However, when I upload a larger file (20MB), the file still uploads fine but I don't get the required JSON data returned.

Here is my PHP code without the actual file handling:

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['status_cp'] != 1){
    header("Location: index.html");
}

// include the files for accessing the 'live' database
include('assets/database/dbConfig.php');
include('assets/database/dbFns.php');
include('assets/utilities/ImageResizer.php');

$ret["success"] = false;

$picsFolder = "pics/";
$uploadsFolder = "uploads/";

if(isset($_FILES["file"])) {
    // handle the file here...
    $ret["success"] = true;
}

echo json_encode($ret);
?>
```

So, what is getting returned for larger uploads is basically the 'index.html' file. It seems as if the session is expiring and redirects to the HTML!?!.

Also, if I remove the session code as seen at the top of my code, all works as expected; the proper JSON data is returned. However, I want that code in there so not just anyone to call it.

Since I suspected timeout issues I have included the following in a .htaccess file and placed in the root of the website but it makes no difference. Running phpinfo() on the server confirms these settings are being used.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 110M 
php_value post_max_size 120M
php_value max_execution_time 10800
php_value max_input_time 10800
```

The javascript code that is calling the PHP:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);

var uploadURL = "upload.php";
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
    xhr: function() {
        var xhrobj = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

        if (xhrobj.upload) {
            xhrobj.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                var percent = 0;
                var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                var total = event.total;

                if (event.lengthComputable) {
                    percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                    console.log('percent: ' + percent);
                }

                // set progress
                status.setProgress(percent);
            });
        }

        return xhrobj;
    },
    url: uploadURL,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    }
});
```

Thank you. Any assistance is appreciated.

**[EDIT]**

Results from a `var_dump($_POST, $_FILES);`

```
array(5) {
  ["typeId"]=>
  string(6) "tender"
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "27"
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "Test"
  ["documentName"]=>
  string(7) "Testing"
  ["transferToFtp"]=>
  string(4) "true"
}
array(1) {
  ["file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(25) "mbam-setup-2.1.6.1022.exe"
    ["type"]=>
    string(24) "application/x-msdownload"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(48) "/storage/nfs/hmu_storage_02/shared/tmp/phpFrkeye"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(21546080)
  }
}
```

Comment: the session issue needs more investigating : if you can't find the session variable value you are looking for there should be a damn good reason somewhere (maybe it's not set in the first place, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this in the top:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

If you feel that the session is not getting set, try using:

```
session_start();
```

The above code is mandatory. I couldn't see that in your code.

Comment: Yes, `session_start();` is in my code. I forgot to include it in the sample. I placed `header("Content-type: application/json");` as the very first line but it made no difference?

Comment: @Terry Have you enabled all the errors? What does the error log or access log show?

Comment: Also you have used `if(isset($_FILES["file"]))`, so how are you calling this PHP? Show me the previous HTML code that triggers this call.

Comment: I will need to look into how I can enable error logging. I have modified my original post to show the javascript code which is calling the PHP code.

Comment: @Terry Just put `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` on the top.

Comment: OKay, can you do this? `var_dump($_POST, $_FILES)` and tell me what's the output? @Terry?

Comment: results from `var_dump($_POST, $_FILES);` Sorry, comments don't allow formatting. `array(5) {
  ["typeId"]=>
  string(6) "tender"
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "27"
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "VDM Test"
  ["documentName"]=>
  string(7) "Testing"
  ["transferToFtp"]=>
  string(4) "true"
}
array(1) {
  ["file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(25) "mbam-setup-2.1.6.1022.exe"
    ["type"]=>
    string(24) "application/x-msdownload"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(48) "/storage/nfs/hmu_storage_02/shared/tmp/phpFrkeye"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(21546080)
  }
}`

Comment: @Terry Update it in your question by using [edit] question.

Comment: What was the issue? Have you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that session variables were indeed being set incorrectly but @Praveen sped up the debugging process by providing valuable information. My local copy of login.php had the correct session variables being set so I initially did not look at it. Finally, I did look at the login.php file that was actually on the server and it indeed was different...

Uploading the correct copy to the server corrected the issue and JSON data is now returning as expected.